# can't seem to see logo.jpg inside the header_container div?

Tags: css

I can't figure out why the image is not resolving inside the div id="header_container"

everything looks ok, the image is on the server,,, what's the issue here?

http://winteradagency.com/mrw/index.php

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: hm, maybe you should cross check your results in another browser, at least it works here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background image URL's in a CSS file are relative to the URL of the CSS file itself, not to the URL of the parent HTML page which included the CSS file.

So, to fix your particular problem, change `images/logo.jpg` to `../images/logo.jpg`, otherwise it is trying to lookup the image in `styles/images/logo.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

When you make a CSS `url()` directive a relative path, it is relative to the CSS file, not the page the CSS is on.  In your case, the `header_container` directive is:

```
background-image: url(images/logo.jpg);
```

Because your CSS file is in `/mrw/styles/styles.css`, the path that the image is being looked for at is `/mrw/styles/images/logo.jpg`.  You need to adjust your CSS directive accordingly.  One of the following should work:

```
background-image: url(/mrw/images/logo.jpg);
```

or

```
background-image: url(../images/logo.jpg);
```